# how to add social follow button in php

Tags: php, social-networking, linkedin-api, google-plus, twitter-follow

I am developing a web that has a social follow on twitter, google+ and linkedin.

I have search on the net but I have no luck.

is there any example on how can I have the follow link and the number of the follower using php? for example:

```
my@twitter.com > 100 followers
my@googleplus > 100 followers
my@linkedin >200 follower
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LinkedIn: http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

For Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button

For Google+: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/

Everything you should need to know is there. It should be plain HTML and not PHP that's being used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the buttons provided by linkedin and Google+?

Please check https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/ and http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins